# Ruby on Rails: How to have Each_do_with_index not update Index of my Object?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, indexing

I am trying to display my large_group objects so that only ones in a certain semester will have the semester displayed with its respective parameters. However, if I edit one of my large_group objects, it seems to update the index of that object. For example, editing Large Group 1 would change its index from 1 to 7.

```
<% @large_group.each_with_index do |large_group, index| %>
        <tr class="borderless">
            <% if index == 0 || large_group.semester != @large_group[index - 1].semester %>
                <td class="test_font"> <%= large_group.semester %> </td>
                <% else %>
                <td></td>
            <% end %>

            <h1><%= puts "#{large_group} at index #{index}"%></h1>

            <td class="nicer"> <%= link_to "large group " + large_group.session_number.to_s, large_group_path(large_group)%> </td>
            <td class="nicer2"> 
<%= large_group.date.strftime("%m/%d")%> </td>
```

And Here is my large_group_controller

```
class LargeGroupsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_large_group, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :shuffle, :reset, :add_or_reassign]

def index
        @large_group = LargeGroup.all
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.json
          end
    end

def update

        if @large_group.update_attributes(large_group_params)
            flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated #{@large_group.session_number}."
            redirect_to large_group_path 
        else 
            flash[:error] = "Error in editing Large Group #{@large_group.session_number}"
            redirect_to large_groups_path
        end 
    end 

    def edit
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.js
        end
    end
```

how do I make sure the index does not update after I try to edit my object?

Answer (score 0):

I think by default doing `LargeGroup.all` returns the records based on `updated_at` value in ascending order. Change your index action code as follows:

```
@large_group = LargeGroup.order('created_at ASC')
```

In case you want them in latest created order change `'ASC'` to `'DESC'`.

Comment: `LargeGroup.all` will do `SELECT * FROM large_groups`, i.e. the return order will be undefined.